# Pandas Groupby using information from other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have the following two dataframes:

Table 1:

```
Key1 Key2 Value1  Other Data

1     2     5      foo
3     1     6      bar
```

and

Table 2:

```
Key1 Key2 Property1 Property2

1     2     5       7     
3     1     6       8      
1     3     7       7      
2     1     4       4      
2     1     6       6     
2     1     8       5
```

In Table 1 the order of the keys doesn't matter. Table 1 has no duplicates.
In Table 2 the order of the keys does matter. Table 2 has duplicates.
I'm quite new to pandas, but as I understand the concept of groupby this should be the perfect tool to go.
I hope that I explained my problem well enough.

Edit:
Regarding the comments I would like to split the problem.

First Step:
Merge Table 1 and Table 2. I think this has to be hierachical.

```
Key 1 Key 2 Value 1 Other Data Key1 Key2 Property1 Propterty2
 1       2     5        foo       1   2     5           7   
                                  2   1     4           4
                                  2   1     6           6
                                  2   1     8           5
 3       1     6        bar       3   1     6           8
                                  1   3     7           7
```

Step2: Filter values based on Value 1. If **Property 1=Value 1 +- 1** then hold the entry, if not delete it. In the example here this results in:

```
Key 1 Key 2 Value 1 Other Data Key1 Key2 Property1 Propterty2
 1       2     5        foo       1   2     5           7   
                                  2   1     4           4
                                  2   1     6           6
 3       1     6        bar       3   1     6           8
                                  1   3     7           7
```

Step3: Reshape and build mean:
Build the mean of all pairs remaining (here mean of the two entrys for (2,1)). Then reshape the dataframe.

```
Key 1 Key 2 Value 1 Other Data  Property1(i,j) Propterty2(i,j)  Property1(j,i)  Propterty2(j,i) 
 1       2     5        foo         5               7                5           5
 3       1     6        bar         6               8                7           7
```

Step4: Handle missing data. If I would only have data for (1,3) in Table 2 but no for (3,1) then he should fill this values up with NaN in Step3. In the last step I would like to delete all rows with a NaN then.

Comment: _"I hope that I explained my problem well enough."_ No, no you did not - at least for me. The paragraph before is really unclear and hard to read.

You should probably split this process up in multiple smaller steps to understand, because now you seem to want to merge, aggregate and filter all in one step.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried to split the process in smaller steps. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge twice:

```
new_df = df2.groupby(['Key1','Key2'], as_index=False).mean()

(df1.merge(new_df, 
          left_on=['Key1','Key2'],
          right_on=['Key2','Key1'],
          suffixes=('', '_add'))
    .drop(['Key1_add','Key2_add'], axis=1)
    .merge(new_df, on=['Key1','Key2'],
           suffixes=['(i,j)','(j,i)'] )
)
```

output:

```
   Key1  Key2  Value1 OtherData  Property1(i,j)  Property2(i,j)  \
0     1     2       5       foo             5.5             5.0   
1     3     1       6       bar             7.0             7.0   

   Property1(j,i)  Property2(j,i)  
0             5.0             7.0  
1             6.0             8.0
```

Comment: I tried your solution but in your first step of building the mean you don't respect the condition that Property1=Value1 +-1. Also I described my problem much too complicated. I edited the question and hope it's clearer now what I want to achieve.